# add a </tr><tr> automatically after every 4 <td>

Tags: php

I have below script which add  after every 2 , **now what i want is make this script to work after every 4**

right now i'm showing 2 images per row, i want to make it 4 images per row & then new line should start.

what i want

Row 1 - 1,2,3,4
Row 2 - 5,6,7,8

any idea?

```
<table class="views-view-grid cols-4">
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    if( have_rows('picture') ):

    echo "<tr>";
    $currentCount = -1;
    while ( have_rows('picture') ) : the_row();
    {
        //echo "<td>";
    ?>
    <td>
    <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="<?php the_sub_field('image');?>" width="220" height="220" alt="">
    </td>
    <?php   
     //echo"</td>";

        $currentCount = ($currentCount + 1) % 2;
        if($currentCount == 1)
        {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }


    endwhile;

    else :
    // no rows found

    endif;

    ?>
     </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$currentCount` as a counter variable and have it incremented in each iteration of `while()` loop. Also, you need to change the inner `if` condition accordingly.

```
<table class="views-view-grid cols-4">
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    if( have_rows('picture') ):
        echo "<tr>";
        $currentCount = 1;
        echo '<tr>';
        while ( have_rows('picture') ) : 
            the_row();
            ?>
            <td>
                <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="<?php the_sub_field('image');?>" width="220" height="220" alt="">
            </td>
            <?php   
            if($currentCount % 4 == 0){
                echo '</tr><tr>';
            }
            ++$currentCount;
        endwhile;
        echo '</tr>';
    else :
        // no rows found
    endif;
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```